# How to force all descendent processes in the same Windows Processor Group?

Tags: windows, inheritance, processor

I need to run an application in a Processor Group. This application creates its own subprocesses.

I have been able to force the main process into the Processor Group that I want, but none of the methods that I have found ("start /node x" command, flag INHERIT_PARENT_AFFINITY in CreateProcess() and flag PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PREFERRED_NODE) is inherited into the grandchildren processes.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Job Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161(v=vs.85).aspx). `JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION` can force affinity or you can use `JOBOBJECT_ASSOCIATE_COMPLETION_PORT` to get the `JOB_OBJECT_MSG_NEW_PROCESS` message and manually set the affinity.

Comment: Thank's a lot for the reply. JobObjectBasicLimitInformation is not Processor Group aware, but you pointed me to the right direction. There is a JobObjectGroupInformation that in my preliminary tests works. I create the Job Object and assign it to my current process. This changes the Processor Group for the current process when not the same, and all subprocesses seem to inherit it. :)